# Can you transfer characters on a WoW account to yourself?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have played WoW for years but have not been playing for the past year or so (started in TBC, stopped about a year or more ago). I am interested in just playing around again without paying, so I am thinking about making a new account and playing a bunch of toons to level 20 just to see if the game feels fun to me again.

If I do this and end up liking it I would like to upgrade the account to paid for a month or more to get RAF benefits. If I do this, would I then be able to link my old account and my new one in some way so that I could play all characters I have ever played before?

If the answer is no, is it possible that my "son" could make a new account and do the same thing and then transfer the characters to me (since my legal name would be on the account since I would be making the account for him?)

Comment: The following forum post indicates that transferring from a starter account to a non starter account requires that you contact billing [Transferring char from starter to full](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/4142247711)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple accounts that are all connected to one battle.net account.

So you would log into battle.net with your old account, and add a trial account to it, when you log into the game using the battle.net launcher, you can then select which one you want to play with. If your old account has expired, it will probably be greyed out.

The following screenshot indicates what this might look like.

[image: battle.net launcher]

I happen to have 5 live accounts and 1 starter edition account. I don't pay for the starter edition account. If I wanted to transter characters from it to my unlocked accounts I would need to contact customer services.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. One more question, however. Say I make a trial account and get a bunch of level 20's. If I decide to upgrade, am I able to use RAF with that level 20's account or does RAF have to happen before you even make a character. Also, are you able to RAF yourself from two different accounts on the same Bnet account?

Comment: @Laurbert515 You can use "Recruit A Friend" to sign up new world of warcraft accounts and assign them to your battle.net account. With regards to using RAF on your existing trial account you wont be able to unless it was created from an RAF invitation.

Comment: You can RAF the same bnet account that sends the RAF. Also be aware you still have to pay for a subscription on each individual account. So your main chars on the first account would be governed by one $15/mo subscription, and the new account would be governed by another $15/mo subscription.

Comment: Can you log 2 of your account at the same time?

Comment: @Damek it is possible for one person to play with multiple accounts at the same time, it is not a violation of the game terms, but there is no support for it in the game itself. for more information about that style of play see [World of Warcraft forums on dual-boxing.com](http://www.dual-boxing.com/forums/54-World-of-Warcraft)